# Angular4 router-outlet activate and ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I am trying to update the status of some buttons. Basically there are 3 steps (1, 2 and 3) When on step one, all steps have **not** been visited. When on step 2, step 1 has been visited, when on step 3, step 1 and 2 have been visited and when on the results page, all steps have been visited.

I created an object called visited:

```
export interface IVisited {
    one: boolean;
    two: boolean;
    three: boolean;
}
```

Then I hooked up a method to the **activate** property of the `router-outlet` like this:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="changeLinkState()"></router-outlet>
```

And the method looks like this:

```
changeLinkState() {
  var url = this._router.url;
  if (!this.visited) {
    this.visited = {
      one: false,
      two: false,
      three: false
    };
  }
  switch (url) {
    case '/steps/one':
      this.visited.one = false;
      this.visited.two = false;
      this.visited.three = false;
      break;
    case '/steps/two':
      this.visited.one = true;
      this.visited.two = false;
      this.visited.three = false;
      break;
    case '/steps/three':
      this.visited.one = true;
      this.visited.two = true;
      this.visited.three = false;
      break;
    default:
      this.visited.one = true;
      this.visited.two = true;
      this.visited.three = true;
      break;
  }

  console.log(this.visited);
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: 'true'.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this error from appearing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can put some of you logic inside setTimeout function
for i.e

```
    changeLinkState() {
      var url = this._router.url;
      setTimeout(()=>{
      if (!this.visited) {
        this.visited = {
          one: false,
          two: false,
          three: false
        };
      }
      switch (url) {
        case '/steps/one':
          this.visited.one = false;
          this.visited.two = false;
          this.visited.three = false;
          break;
        case '/steps/two':
          this.visited.one = true;
          this.visited.two = false;
          this.visited.three = false;
          break;
        case '/steps/three':
          this.visited.one = true;
          this.visited.two = true;
          this.visited.three = false;
          break;
        default:
          this.visited.one = true;
          this.visited.two = true;
          this.visited.three = true;
          break;
      }

      console.log(this.visited);
      })
    }
```

I hope this will work.